# How can I run javascript directly and show the output?

Tags: filetype-javascript

I'm just doing some testing with JavaScript language feature with no DOM manipulation. So I'm editing a js file and I'm wondering how to simply run it and show the console output? I installed the [moll/vim-node](https://github.com/moll/vim-node) plugin, but no idea how to run js code.

Comment: You can try something like `:!node %`. This will shell out to the external `node` program, passing the current filename as an argument. Output will be displayed on the screen, and you can press Enter to dismiss it.

Comment: The comment above by @tommcdo is a good concise solution that satisfied all I had been trying to achieve through more complicated means such as slime, et cetera.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Per this [vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Display_output_of_shell_commands_in_new_window) entry you could create a shell execution to new buffer script and then extend it to run your code using node.

```
command! -complete=shellcmd -nargs=+ Shell call s:RunShellCommand(<q-args>)
function! s:RunShellCommand(cmdline)
  let isfirst = 1
  let words = []
  for word in split(a:cmdline)
    if isfirst
      let isfirst = 0  " don't change first word (shell command)
    else
      if word[0] =~ '\v[%#<]'
        let word = expand(word)
      endif
      let word = shellescape(word, 1)
    endif
    call add(words, word)
  endfor
  let expanded_cmdline = join(words)
  botright new
  setlocal buftype=nofile bufhidden=wipe nobuflisted noswapfile nowrap
  call setline(1, 'You entered:  ' . a:cmdline)
  call setline(2, 'Expanded to:  ' . expanded_cmdline)
  call append(line('$'), substitute(getline(2), '.', '=', 'g'))
  silent execute '$read !'. expanded_cmdline
  1
endfunction

command! -complete=file -nargs=* RunJS call s:RunShellCommand('node '.<q-args>)
```

Then if you run `:RunJS %` you should get a new buffer with the output of your node.js execution. Optionally you can call things directly using `:Shell <cmd>`

Answer (score 7):

I think [Codi](https://github.com/metakirby5/codi.vim) is what you are looking for. It supports JavaScript and some other languages.

[image]

Answer (score 5):

No plugin required! You can run node with the shell command `:!`

Run the entire file with `:!/usr/local/bin/node %`

Run the current line with `:exec '!/usr/local/bin/node' '-e'  shellescape(getline('.'))`

Answer (score 0):

#### 2021 Update

Later versions of Vim and NeoVim now have terminal support built-in. Use the `:term(inal)` command to open a new terminal.

#### Original Answer

I highly recommend https://github.com/Shougo/vimshell.vim for this purpose.

Its a vim plugin that allows you to run a terminal within vim. You can open the terminal in a new tab with

```
:VimShellTab
```

or quickfix window with

```
:VimShellPop
```

then you can run commands as usual, i.e.

```
node
```